# Shell lab running test

Tags: linux

When I am testing the shell lab from CMU15-213 on WSL Ubuntus 22.04, the specification told me to execute `make test01` and the command line shows:

```
alexman@Alexman:~/home/shlab$ make test01
./sdriver.pl -t trace01.txt -s ./tsh -a "-p"
/bin/sh: 1: ./sdriver.pl: not found
make: *** [Makefile:29: test01] Error 127
```

Also I have added the /usr/bin/perl to environment $PATH

```
alexman@Alexman:~/home/shlab$ echo $PATH
/home/alexman/.vscode-server/bin/903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compiler:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x64:/mnt/c/Program Files/Eclipse Adoptium/jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot/bin:/mnt/f/WorkStationPro17/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.8/libnvvp:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Python/Python310/:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Java/jdk-14/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/d/Program_Files/NodeJS/Node16:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/Nsight Compute 2022.3.0/:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Java/apache-maven-3.9.5-bin/apache-maven-3.9.5/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Windows Performance Toolkit/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx86/x86:/mnt/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/mnt/d/Softwares/GraphViz/windows_10_cmake_Release_Graphviz-10.0.1-win64/Graphviz-10.0.1-win64/bin:/mnt/c/Users/alexm/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/d/Program_Files/NodeJS/npm:/mnt/d/Program_Files/C++/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/Users/alexm/AppData/Local/Pandoc/:/mnt/c/Users/alexm/.dotnet/tools:/mnt/d/Program_Files/Anaconda3/Scripts:/mnt/d/Softwares/GraphViz/windows_10_cmake_Release_Graphviz-10.0.1-win64/Graphviz-10.0.1-win64/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/bin/perl
```

The perl testing script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use Getopt::Std;
use FileHandle;
use IPC::Open2;

#######################################################################
# sdriver.pl - Shell driver
#
# Copyright (c) 2002, R. Bryant and D. O'Hallaron, All rights reserved.
# May not be used, modified, or copied without permission.
#
# The driver runs a student's shell program as a child, sends 
# commands and signals to the child as directed by a trace file,
# and captures and displays the output produced by the child.
#
# Tracefile format:
# 
# The tracefile consists of text lines that are either blank lines,
# comment lines, driver commands, or shell commands. Blank lines are
# ignored. Comment lines begin with "#" and are echo'd without change 
# to stdout. Driver commands are intepreted  by the driver and are not 
# passed to the child shell. All other lines are shell commands and
# are passed without modification to the shell, which reads them on
# stdin. Output produced by the child on stdout/stderr is read by 
# the parent and printed on its stdout.
#
# Driver commands:
#     TSTP        Send a SIGTSTP signal to the child
#     INT         Send a SIGINT signal to the child 
#     QUIT        Send a SIGQUIT signal to the child
#     KILL        Send a SIGKILL signal to the child
#     CLOSE       Close Writer (sends EOF signal to child)
#     WAIT        Wait() for child to terminate
#     SLEEP <n>   Sleep for <n> seconds
# 
######################################################################

#
# usage - print help message and terminate
#
sub usage 
{
    printf STDERR "$_[0]\n";
    printf STDERR "Usage: $0 [-hv] -t <trace> -s <shellprog> -a <args>\n";
    printf STDERR "Options:\n";
    printf STDERR "  -h            Print this message\n";
    printf STDERR "  -v            Be more verbose\n";
    printf STDERR "  -t <trace>    Trace file\n";
    printf STDERR "  -s <shell>    Shell program to test\n";
    printf STDERR "  -a <args>     Shell arguments\n";
    printf STDERR "  -g            Generate output for autograder\n";
    die "\n" ;
}

# Parse the command line arguments
getopts('hgvt:s:a:');
if ($opt_h) {
    usage();
}
if (!$opt_t) {
    usage("Missing required -t argument");
}
if (!$opt_s) {
    usage("Missing required -s argument");
}
$verbose = $opt_v;
$infile = $opt_t;
$shellprog = $opt_s;
$shellargs = $opt_a;
$grade = $opt_g;

# Make sure the input script exists and is readable
-e $infile
    or die "$0: ERROR: $infile not found\n";
-r $infile
    or die "$0: ERROR: $infile is not readable\n";

# Make sure the shell program exists and is executable
-e $shellprog
    or die "$0: ERROR: $shellprog not found\n";
-x $shellprog
    or die "$0: ERROR: $shellprog is not executable\n";


# Open the input script
open INFILE, $infile
    or die "$0: ERROR: Couldn't open input file $infile: $!\n";

# 
# Fork a child, run the shell in it, and connect the parent
# and child with a pair of unidirectional pipes: 
#     parent:Writer -> child:stdin
#     child:stdout  -> parent:Reader
#
$pid = open2(\*Reader, \*Writer, "$shellprog $shellargs");
Writer->autoflush();

# The autograder will want to know the child shell's pid
if ($grade) {
    print ("pid=$pid\n");
}

# 
# Parent reads a trace file, sends commands to the child shell. 
#
while (<INFILE>) {
    $line = $_;
    chomp($line);

    # Comment line
    if ($line =~ /^#/) {  
    print "$line\n";
    }

    # Blank line
    elsif ($line =~ /^\s*$/) { 
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Ignoring blank line\n";
    }
    }

    # Send SIGTSTP (ctrl-z)
    elsif ($line =~ /TSTP/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sending SIGTSTP signal to process $pid\n";
    }
    kill 'TSTP', $pid;
    }

    # Send SIGINT (ctrl-c)
    elsif ($line =~ /INT/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sending SIGINT signal to process $pid\n";
    }
    kill 'INT', $pid;
    }

    # Send SIGQUIT (whenever we need graceful termination)
    elsif ($line =~ /QUIT/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sending SIGQUIT signal to process $pid\n";
    }
    kill 'QUIT', $pid;
    }

    # Send SIGKILL 
    elsif ($line =~ /KILL/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sending SIGKILL signal to process $pid\n";
    }
    kill 'KILL', $pid;
    }

    # Close pipe (sends EOF notification to child)
    elsif ($line =~ /CLOSE/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Closing output end of pipe to child $pid\n";
    }
    close Writer;
    }

    # Wait for child to terminate
    elsif ($line =~ /WAIT/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Waiting for child $pid\n";
    }
    wait;
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Child $pid reaped\n";
    }
    }

    # Sleep
    elsif ($line =~ /SLEEP (\d+)/) {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sleeping $1 secs\n";
    }
    sleep $1;
    }

    # Unknown input
    else {
    if ($verbose) {
        print "$0: Sending :$line: to child $pid\n";
    }
    print Writer "$line\n";
    }
}

# 
# Parent echoes the output produced by the child.
#
close Writer;
if ($verbose) {
    print "$0: Reading data from child $pid\n";
}
while ($line = <Reader>) {
    print $line;
}
close Reader;

# Finally, parent reaps child
wait;

if ($verbose) {
    print "$0: Shell terminated\n";
}

exit;
```

And the makefile is defined as follows:

```
# Makefile for the CS:APP Shell Lab

TEAM = NOBODY
VERSION = 1
HANDINDIR = /afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f02/L5/handin
DRIVER = ./sdriver.pl
TSH = ./tsh
TSHREF = ./tshref
TSHARGS = "-p"
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O2
FILES = $(TSH) ./myspin ./mysplit ./mystop ./myint

all: $(FILES)

##################
# Handin your work
##################
handin:
    cp tsh.c $(HANDINDIR)/$(TEAM)-$(VERSION)-tsh.c


##################
# Regression tests
##################

# Run tests using the student's shell program
test01:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace01.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test02:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace02.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test03:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace03.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test04:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace04.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test05:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace05.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test06:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace06.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test07:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace07.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test08:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace08.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test09:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace09.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test10:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace10.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test11:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace11.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test12:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace12.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test13:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace13.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test14:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace14.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test15:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace15.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)
test16:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace16.txt -s $(TSH) -a $(TSHARGS)

# Run the tests using the reference shell program
rtest01:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace01.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest02:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace02.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest03:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace03.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest04:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace04.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest05:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace05.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest06:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace06.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest07:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace07.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest08:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace08.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest09:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace09.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest10:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace10.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest11:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace11.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest12:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace12.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest13:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace13.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest14:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace14.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest15:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace15.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)
rtest16:
    $(DRIVER) -t trace16.txt -s $(TSHREF) -a $(TSHARGS)


# clean up
clean:
    rm -f $(FILES) *.o *~
```

The file structre is as follows:

```
alexman@Alexman:~/home/shlab$ ls -l
total 236
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman  2615 Feb 29 17:27 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   783 Feb 29 17:27 README
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 16264 Mar  1 22:27 myint
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   654 Feb 29 17:27 myint.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 16136 Mar  1 22:27 myspin
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   442 Feb 29 17:27 myspin.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 16224 Mar  1 22:27 mysplit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   657 Feb 29 17:27 mysplit.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 16264 Mar  1 22:27 mystop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   660 Feb 29 17:27 mystop.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman  5353 Feb 29 17:27 sdriver.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman    63 Feb 29 17:27 trace01.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman    65 Feb 29 17:27 trace02.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman    72 Feb 29 17:27 trace03.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman    94 Feb 29 17:27 trace04.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   182 Feb 29 17:27 trace05.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   116 Feb 29 17:27 trace06.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   201 Feb 29 17:27 trace07.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   203 Feb 29 17:27 trace08.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   250 Feb 29 17:27 trace09.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   249 Feb 29 17:27 trace10.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   185 Feb 29 17:27 trace11.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   220 Feb 29 17:27 trace12.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   276 Feb 29 17:27 trace13.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   495 Feb 29 17:27 trace14.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   502 Feb 29 17:27 trace15.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman   272 Feb 29 17:27 trace16.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 22512 Mar  5 22:11 tsh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 23324 Mar  5 22:11 tsh.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman 19278 Feb 29 17:27 tshref
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexman alexman  6300 Feb 29 17:27 tshref.out
```

How to solve this problem? Is there any command that could quickly fix this?

Comment: The whole point of a fully-qualified path in the shebang is that it doesn't depend on the PATH (if the shebang were `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, _then_ you'd need `PATH` to include `/usr/bin` -- no `perl` in it, just the directory _containing_ that executable). More likely you're missing a shared library -- `ldd /usr/bin/perl` will let you check whether the library dependencies of perl are all available. BTW, note that each file has only one shebang; `#!/usr/bin/perl` is used, `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` is ignored.

Comment: Anyhow, a good place to start would be to run `/usr/bin/perl --version`. If perl doesn't work at all, you can rule out anything that's related to the Makefile or the contents of the specific perl script at hand, and focus on trying to diagnose what's happening loading the executable.

Comment: Bigger picture, what's the environment all this is running in? Is it a single-purpose Docker container? A VM created only for this use? A shared multi-user system? If the latter, what's the context (distro, etc)?

Comment: I am just using the windows system of linux(version 2) to run these commands and scripts. and the /usr/bin/perl --version seems fine, it shows "This is perl 5, version 34, subversion 0 (v5.34.0) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 60 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail"

Comment: That being the case, my first suspicion is that your perl script might be saved with DOS newlines instead of UNIX ones. If the actual shebang `#!/usr/bin/perl` has a CR character after it (as is correct for Windows but wrong on UNIX), that would make it look for an executable named `perl$'\r'`, which doesn't actually exist.